How to access non-primitive type of data from a k8s customer resource using dynamic client + unstructured
I have a K8s custom resource where the Spec looks like the following:
type Spec1 struct {
  field1 string
  field2 int64
  field3 []MyType
}

type MyType struct {
  a string
  b string
}

Now I am using dynamic client to access this k8s resource and using unstructured.Example:
f1 :=  unstructured.NestedString(obj.Object, "spec", "field1")
How can I access field3[0].a here which is of type MyType?
unstructured documentation has no information about accessing non-primitive data type.

field3 being a list (Go slice) looks like it doesn't match well with the unstructured API.  You might need NestedSlice to get the entire list, then (in Go) cast to a map[string]interface{}, at which point you can use NestedString again.
